# make hibernate entity work with postgres and sqlite for json field

Tags: hibernate, sqlite, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-types, hibernate-postgresql

There is a requirement to run the same version of the application on a remote device ( backed with sqlite ) as well as on the cloud ( backed with postgres ). The account entity looks like:

```
        @Entity
        @Table(name="account")
        public class Account extends BaseEntity{

        @Id
        @Column(name="id")
        private String id;

        @Column(name="valid_from")
        private LocalDateTime validFrom;

        @Column(name="expires_on")
        private LocalDateTime expiresOn;

        @Column(name="events")
        @Convert(converter = EventListConverter.class)
        @NotNull
        @NotEmpty
        private List<Event> events;
```

The `EventListConverter` is converting the `events` to JSON string and back to `List<Event>` for SQLite. However, the `events` column is of type `jsonb` on Postgres - how can we make it work for both ?

Constraints:
POSTGRES schema cant be changed  ( events in SQLite could be changed to binary though )

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is the generated DDL because you use hbm2ddl update?

I would recommend that you do schema updates through a tool like Liquibase or Flyway as these tools can define DDL per DBMS. If you really must use hbm2ddl, you could subclass the `Dialect` implementation and provide a custom `TableExporter`. You need to copy a bit of the `StandardTableExporter` but it's doable, you can remap the column types to whatever you think is more appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the response. We are using `Flyway` to run the DDL for `sqlite` when hosted for the remote machine, while we have to adapt to the existing postgres schema for the cloud. Could you give some more reference on extending  the `Dialect` part on remapping the column types ?

Comment: Since you are using Flyway, what is the problem with writing a custom DDL for PostgreSQL? You just have to copy `org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.StandardTableExporter#getSqlCreateStrings` and when rendering the SQL type you do your custom mapping e.g. from "JSONB" to "text" for SQLite

Comment: I am fairly new with hibernate and flyway, not on the same page here :) 

Couple of questions, 

1. flyway schema migration on startup - we want to manage only sqlite  with this - postgres is what is existing and also used by another application ( so no altering there )  

2. once flyway migration completes and service is up ( micronuat api ) - how does flyway help in doing the ORM with target database , isn't it at hibernate entity level  ?

Comment: I am able to work around the problem by making the  `events` field a string type and doing https://vladmihalcea.com/map-string-jpa-property-json-column-hibernate/ and have another transient field that gets de-serialised version of the string